# Windows 2012 R2 AD Admin Passwords not Expiring

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

On our Active Directory server our Domain Administrator accounts are not forcing resets of passwords after 90 days as defined in our Group Policy:

[image: Activie Directory Group Policy Settings]

All Domain Admins are on the group policy.  Also, when we pull their expiration dates they are for several months ago.  The expiration date has passed.  Any ideas on what could be exempting Domain Admins from being forced to reset their passwords?

The users do not have a Password never expires checked.

This is defined in Default Domain Policy.

Comment: What GPO is the setting defined in?

Comment: Default Domain Policy

Comment: If you run `gpresult /h gpresult.html` on your domain controllers, does it show the settings in effect?

Comment: Is there more than one password policy in the domain?

Comment: `1.` Password policies are Computer Configuration settings, not User Configuration settings. `2.` Have you checked the properties of those user accounts to see if the "Password never expires" checkbox is checked?

Comment: @joeqwerty Password Never Expires is not checked for those accounts.

Comment: @GregAskew I only see this  Policy - Setting - Winning GPO /
Enforce user logon restrictions - Enabled - Default Domain Policy

Comment: Account expiration and password expiration are different things. You wrote ...when we pull their expiration dates... Exactly which attribute are you looking at on these accounts? Should be looking at pwdLastSet and adding 90 days to that to determine when password should expire. Also, do you have Fine Grained Password policies deployed? Run powershell: `Get-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -Filter *`

Answer (score 0):

Password policy applies to computers which hosts these accounts. Make sure this particular GPO applies to domain controllers as they are the ones which store user accounts.